# Submit form with ajax within a modal with a response of another form. The second form will not post to another ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a form within a bootstrap modal window. Depending on the information added to the first form the response is different.  I submit the form with ajax and keep the modal open to display the response message(s) from the submitted form.  If the condition needs additional information I have another form within the response message that I need filled out.  When I submit the second form it only posts the first form again.  I cannot figure out how to get the posted data from the second form to submit even though it appears it does.  The second form is in the source and it all appears as it should post just fine.  I am making a very similar ajax post with the second form, the function executes but with the first form information only.

```
    function submit_formList(action) {  
     $('#FormDiv').hide();
     $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: './response_page.cfm',
        data :   $("form").serialize()      
    })
    .done(function (data) {
                $('#response').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                $('#response').html("<b>We're sorry there was a problem.</b>");
                $('#FormDiv').show();

            });
        return false;
     }
```

within the $('#response').html(data); is the second form.  How would I get that form into the DOM to be able to submit it?

Comment: with `$("#FormId").submit();`just make sure the form loads into the DOM and has id, this should do the trick `.done(function (data) {$('#response').html(data);$("#FormId").submit();})`

Comment: Bummer, $("#FormId").submit(); does not work.  The issue is that I am not able to get the form to load in DOM to use it from with in the data of the response.  It is a form after a form response I need to get in DOM and submit.  I need to be able to use ajax to submit the data from the second form, I do not want to reload the entire page.  Thanks.

Comment: where that 2nd form located, is it on the same page where the first form is or it is coming from `response_page.cfm`?

Comment: it is coming from the response_page.cfm so it is within the response of the first form post.

Comment: I am going to try a different approach.